# Batch para impedir que el usuario cambie su fondo de pantalla

Tags: windows, batch, .bat

Con el siguiente código batch, logro que se cambie el fondo de pantalla al ejecutar un archivo `.bat`

```
@echo off

reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d "%~dp0wallmaper.png" /f 

reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v WallpaperStyle /f /t REG_SZ /d 10

%SystemRoot%\System32\rundll32.exe user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters
```

Necesito evitar que el usuario pueda cambiar su fondo de pantalla. Conozco dos formas:

1. **GPEDIT**: Configuración de usuario > Plantillas Administrativas > Panel de Control > Personalizacion > Impedir cambiar el fondo de pantalla > Habilitada
2. **REGEDIT**: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies` > Nuevo > Key > `ActiveDesktop` > Nuevo > `DWORD (32-bit)` > `NoChangingWallPaper` > 1

Ambas son manuales, y sé que cualquier usuario puede revertir este bloqueo, eso no me preocupa.

**Lo que necesito es que este bloqueo se pueda ejecutar desde el mismo comando batch que cambia el fondo de pantalla.**

Basándome en el anterior código, intenté lo siguiente:

```
reg add "HKEY_Current_User\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\ActiveDesktop" /v NoChangingWallPaper /t REG_DWORD /d 1
```

Esto básicamente hace lo mismo que la segunda forma anteriormente descrita:

[image: Ejemplo imagen regedit]

Y aunque cambia el fondo correctamente, y se agrega la entrada en el registro, sigue permitiendo cambiar el fondo de forma común y corriente.

¿Estoy omitiendo algo al respecto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

al parecer es [un error ya conocido](https://superuser.com/questions/1298198/change-the-wallpaper-without-delaying-using-batch-file).

La solución que se plantea, aunque no es la más ortodoxa, consiste en reiniciar el servicio de Explorador de Windows, lo cual funciona.

```
@echo off

reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /t REG_SZ /d "%~dp0wallmaper.png" /f 

reg add "HKEY_Current_User\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\ActiveDesktop" /v NoChangingWallPaper /t REG_DWORD /d 1

reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v WallpaperStyle /f /t REG_SZ /d 10

%SystemRoot%\System32\rundll32.exe user32.dll, UpdatePerUserSystemParameters

taskkill /f /im explorer.exe

explorer
```

Espero encontrar una solución más práctica, y pasaré por acá actualizando esta entrada.